# Check if name is valid with Proper case and Max one space

Tags: java, regex, validation, names

I searched for all regex exp but didn't find any matching my needs.

- [Regular expression to allow spaces between words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472764/regular-expression-to-allow-spaces-between-words)
- [Regular expression to allow alphanumeric, max one space etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218127/regular-expression-to-allow-alphanumeric-max-one-space-etc)
- [Regex, every non-alphanumeric character except white space or colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053541/regex-every-non-alphanumeric-character-except-white-space-or-colon)

In none of the above did I get a solution:

> I need to check that the name is valid if
> => First letter every word should be caps
> => Rest all letters of each word should be small
> => Name should have only alpha char A-Z and a-z
> => First word Length should be min 3
> => Name should not have more than one space between words

Ex : 
sujay       => false 
Sujay       => true

Sujay u     => false 
Sujay U     => true

Sujay U n   => false 
Sujay U N   => true

SuJay U     => false 
Sujay UN    => false 
Sujay Uls   => true

Sujay9      => false 
Su          => false 
Su U        => false 
Sujay U N   => true 
Sujay Uls Nat=> true

|*| Check function used :

```
static boolean chkNamVldFnc(String namVar)
{
    String namRegExpVar = "[A-Z][A-Za-z ]{2,}";

    Pattern pVar = Pattern.compile(namRegExpVar);
    Matcher mVar = pVar.matcher(namVar);
    return mVar.matches();
}
```

|*| Try 1 :

```
String namRegExpVar = "[A-Z][A-Za-z ]{2,}";
```

|*| Try 2 :

```
String namRegExpVar = "[A-Z][a-z]{2,}+//s[A-Z][a-z]{2,}";
```

|*| Try 3 :

```
String NamRegExpVar = "[A-Z][a-z]{2,}||[A-Z][a-z]{2,}+//s[A-Z][a-z]";
```

Kindly help me with Proper Regular Exp :

**I also want to know why we should start Reg Exp with ^ and end with $**

Comment: Two last ones have 2 spaces and they are true - how's that?

Comment: `Name shud have only one space`. `Sujay U N => true` this name has two spaces, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry edited the question now... Plz ignore previous

Comment: Now, `Sujay U` is both *true* and *false* - why? See https://regex101.com/r/tMEQTN/1

Comment: `Rest all letters of each word should be small` -- I disapprove of this regex.

Comment: In true case U is caps and in false case u is smal. In simple users shud enter only proper case Names

Comment: @SujayUN You should format the test data as code. Multiple spaces got lost in the body.

Comment: I was not aware of the website https://regex101.com/ and test data format. Its really helpful and will follow. Thank you for good suggestion.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Ask me about the one where each word has to begin with a capital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]{2,}(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*$
```

- First name must start with letter A-Z, followed by at least 2 letters a-z
- Optionally, there can be names following the first name, seperated by a space and beginning with letter A-Z, and followed by optional letters a-z

Comment: This is what I was looking for... but  Can u explain why we need to use * mark.... Thank you @dave

Comment: @dave Did you just copy the regex from my suggestion?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, I did not see that until just now.  We came up with the same regex!

Comment: Why the `^` and `$`?  If OP is using the regular expression in any sensible way, these are redundant.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Without those, the text `Sujay u` would match, since the non-capturing group portion of the regex doesn't need to match anything

Comment: @dave, you are wrong. If used with `.matches()`, anchors are not necessary. It is a pet peeve, not really an issue.

Comment: No, @dave.  `"Sujay u".matches("[A-Z][a-z]{2,}(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*")` is false.

Comment: Does that answer match: Sujay U => false   ?

Comment: @SujayUN As per your request, I voted on your question.

Comment: While this answer meets the requirements of the question, I feel the need to point out for posterity that there are three users commenting on this thread (under what seem to be their real names), whose names do not match the regex for various reasons.  If you came here looking for a regex for a person's name, you have not found one.